# How to set value for an input in a form using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hello i wanted to set value for an input inside a form how can I access here the html part:

```
<form id="starRate" action="https://nanoclub.ir/online_festival/starRate" data-id="24">
  <input name="star" value="5" class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

and here is the python part:

```
    form = driver.find_element_by_id('starRate')
    #this is the form i wanted to access
    
    input_ = form.find_element_by_class_name('star star-5')
    # and this is the input wanted to set value for 5
```

Comment: If you are looking at input field like textbox sendKeys function will do the work.

If you looking to select a radio button this might help. 
https://www.guru99.com/checkbox-and-radio-button-webdriver.html

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element to set value for 5 star you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.star.star-5#star-5[name='star'][value='5']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='star star-5' and @id='star-5'][@name='star' and @value='5']").click()
  ```

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.star.star-5#star-5[name='star'][value='5']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='star star-5' and @id='star-5'][@name='star' and @value='5']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```